# Why boundary condition on Green's function?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, greens-function

Say I have a linear operator $L$ and I define its Green's function by $LG(x,y)=\delta(x-y)$. Then the problem of finding $f(x)$ such that $Lf(x)=g(x)$ for given $g(x)$ admits as solution $f(x)=\int G(x,y)g(y)dy$.

Now, I read everywhere that I must impose on $G$ the same boundary conditions that are imposed on $f$. So, if we want $f(0)=0$, say, then we must also impose $G(0,y)=0$.

I don't understand this. I mean, we have $f(0)=\int G(0,y)g(y)dy$. This integral can be zero without forcing $G(0,y)=0$, which seems as overkill.

What is the deal?

Comment: If you don't impose the boundary condition on the Green's function level. at the end, you still need to verify the solution constructed satisfied the condition. It is usually harder that way. For most of these problem, the solution is unique. If you find a solution, you find all solution, Why not make your life easier earlier in the game.

Comment: @achillehui Ah, uniqueness. Yes, that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

A possible point of view for many linear problems of the form $Lf = g$ on $\Omega$ and $f=\phi$ on $ \partial \Omega$. Two observations: (1) Set $\phi=0$, then it is easier to construct a space with zero boundary conditions where the inverse $L^{-1}$ is welldefined. (2) If you can find a harmonic function $h_\phi$ for the harmonic problem ($g=0$), then linearity allows to built a solution $f:= h_\phi+L^{-1}g$.

For example if $L=\frac d{dx}$ then (1) one can use the [Bounded Inverse Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_inverse_theorem) to show the existence of $L^{-1}(=\int_0^xdy)$, by constructing an appropriate norm $\|\cdot\|_{L}=\|\cdot\|_{C^1}$ on an appropriate space
\begin{align}
L:& C^1[0,1]\cap\{f(0)=0\} \to  C[0,1], 
\end{align}
and (2) pick $h_\phi=\phi$.

Alternatively you could define the Green's function distributionally to include boundary conditions as $G(x,y)=\mathbf 1(x\ge y)+\phi\delta_0(x-y)$.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
The solution is given by
\begin{align}
\mrm{f}\pars{x} & = \ell_{p}\pars{x} + \int\mrm{G}\pars{x,y}\,\dd y\,,\qquad
\overbrace{\qquad\mrm{f}\pars{a} = \varphi_{a}\qquad}
^{\mbox{Boundary Condition}}
\end{align}

> where $\ds{L\,\ell_{p}\pars{x} = 0}$ and $\ds{\ell_{p}\pars{x}}$ satisfies the *given* boundary condition at $\ds{x = a}$. Namely,
>   $\ds{\ell_{p}\pars{a} = \varphi_{a}}$. In order that $\ds{\mrm{f}\pars{x}}$ satisfies that boundary condition you'll impose $\ds{\mrm{G}\pars{a,y} = 0}$ because

$$
\mrm{f}\pars{a}  =
\ell_{p}\pars{a} + \int\mrm{G}\pars{a,y}\,\dd y =
\varphi_a + \int\mrm{G}\pars{a,y}\,\dd y
$$

> Namely, the boundary condition $\ds{\mrm{f}\pars{a} = \varphi_{a}}$ is *satisfied* by *imposing* $\ds{\mrm{G}\pars{a,y} = 0}$.

Comment: Of course the red integral will be zero if $G(a,y)=0$. However, the red integral could also be zero without imposing this. I don't see how the red integral being zero implies $G(a,y)=0$. Does it? That is the question.

Comment: @thedude You're right. There isn't such implication. We $\underline{\mathrm{impose}}$ ( or choose or set ) the condition $\mathrm{G}\left(a,y\right) = 0$. It $\color{red}{\texttt{doesn't mean}}$ that
$\int\mathrm{G}\left(a,y\right)\,\mathrm{d}y = 0 \implies \mathrm{G}\left(a,y\right) = 0$.

Comment: Thanks. So, do we impose that condition just because it is simple, or is there a very strong reason?

Comment: @thedude The reason is that we have to satisfy the boundary condition an yes it's simple.

Answer (score 0):

At least when the condition is $f(a)=0$ I think I understand. The point is that the prescription $f(a)=\int G(a,y)g(y)dy=0$ must be true for *any* function $g(x)$. This is only possible if $G(a,y)=0$.

For more general conditions, the situation is still not clear to me.